# Am I eligible for transit without visa at Heathrow Airport?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, f1-visas

I will be traveling from Chicago to Copenhagen on 15th December with an overnight layover at Heathrow airport (Terminal 3, American airlines). I'll be reaching UK at 10:45 pm and will be leaving the next day at 8:45 am from Terminal 5.

After going through the official UK government visa site I understand that I should be eligible for transit without visa at UK since I have a US visa (F1). I am an Indian citizen.

I do not have enough time to apply for a visa at this point and I really hope I do not need to. I have tried to contact the embassy and have also tried getting in touch with an immigrant advisor but to no avail. They are either unreachable or cannot appropriately reply to my queries. So any information regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Also if anyone faced a similar situation please let me know what happened.

Comment: It sounds like the UK government site already answered your question?  I'm not sure what you are looking for here.

Comment: @NateEldredge Reassurance!